# Selenium TestNG tests depending on other methods

Tags: java, selenium, testng

**Prerequisites**

The flow of most sites looks something like this: [image: simplified state transition diagram for most sites]

where "dashboard" is where all the fun site-specific business logic takes place.

**What's the problem?**

I'm trying to use Selenium WebDriver and TestNG to test such a site. My code base thus far is something like:

*TestNG.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<!-- Root tag for TestNG.xml will always be suite. The name can be whatever you want -->
<suite name="MyCustomSuite">
    <test name="MyFirstTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mikewarren.testsuites.MercuryToursTest"></class>
            <class name="com.mikewarren.testsuites.MercuryLogin"></class>
            <!-- You can have the class tag for multiple classes of unique name -->

        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

*TestNGGroups.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<!-- Root tag for TestNG.xml will always be suite. The name can be whatever you want -->
<suite name="MySmokeTestSuite">
    <test name="MyFirstTest">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <exclude name="regression"></exclude>
                <include name="smoke"></include>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mikewarren.testsuites.MercuryLogin">
                <methods>
                    <include name="methodName"></include>
                    <!-- you can also include or exclude methods --> 
                </methods>
            </class>
            <!-- You can have the class tag for multiple classes of unique name -->

        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

*MercuryToursTest.java*

```
package com.mikewarren.testsuites;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class MercuryToursTest {
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    protected String url = "http://newtours.demoaut.com";

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Drivers/chromedriver.exe" );
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        // wait a second
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest()
    {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }
}
```

*MercuryLogin.java*

```
package com.mikewarren.testsuites;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.mikewarren.pages.MercuryLoginFactory;


public class MercuryLogin extends MercuryToursTest {
  @Test(priority=0, groups={"smoke"})
  public void validateLandingPage() {
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Welcome: Mercury Tours");  
  }

  @Test(dependsOnMethods="validateLandingPage", 
          priority=2,
          groups={"regression", "somethingElse"}, 
          dataProvider="provideAccountDetailsDynamic")
//  @BeforeTest(groups = {"loginFirst"})
  public void loginToMercury(String username, String password)
  {
      MercuryLoginFactory mlf = new MercuryLoginFactory(driver);
      mlf.driverLogIntoMercury(username, password);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Home')]")).click();
  }

  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] provideAccountDetailsDynamic() throws Exception { 
      File file = new File("src/test/resources/mercuryData.xlsx");
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

      Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");

      int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();
      Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][2];

      /*
       * Data driven framework example.
       * • This is a design patern for test automation where you develop the tests in a manner where they will run
       *    based on provided data. In this case, a tester could have 3 rows data, warranting the test to run 3 
       *    separate times with the given values. 
       *    This allows for configurable automation tests at the hands of a non-developer.
       */
      for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
      {
          Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
          data[i-1] = new Object[] { 
              row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue(),
              row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue()
          };
      }

      return data;
  }


}
```

**What I tried thus far**

Whenever I hit "Run" on `MercuryLogin.java`, it's all good, but as soon as I try to un-comment the `@BeforeTest(groups = {"loginFirst"})` annotation on `MercuryLogin.loginToMercury()` my tests fail horribly. Namely, it tells me that method is expecting two parameters but only gets 0 in the `@Configuration` annotation.

Failing this, I did the following:

I added `MercuryLogin.loginToMercury()` to `loginFirst` group. Then, keeping consistent with the style of the rest of my code base, created `MercuryToursTestLoginFirst.java` :

```
package com.mikewarren.testsuites;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MercuryToursTestLoginFirst extends MercuryToursTest {
    @BeforeClass(dependsOnGroups = "loginFirst")
    public void init()
    {

    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("mock test");
    }
}
```

`test()` works, but it's the only test that actually runs. No login is happening, even though the class invokes it! **How to make sure `MercuryToursTestLoginFirst` actually logs in, and using the data provider?**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using code from tutorial site? 
I think you misunderstood the concept of @beforeTest.

```
@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag is run.
```

You don't combine both tags in 1 (@Test + @BeforeTest). It will not make any sense doing so. You are telling Testng to run this method before others test. @BeforeTest is usually use for config like you did with driver.exe.  Leave your @Test for testing purpose only.

So now what were trying to accomplish with @BeforeTest? Perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm simply trying to automatically have Selenium WebDriver login before performing any tests on the dashboard.

Comment: ok since you mention that it is working, then remove that part. But if you really wish to add another @ BeforeTest in Mercury class, then it should be another method. Best practice, place it before any @ Test.

The order -> 1. BeforeSuite, 2. BeforeTest 3. BeforeMethods 4. Test

Comment: Turns out that the tail of my question was not only not clear, but was danger close to being an XY problem. I'm about to refactor it.